# Simulate keyup.space event for unit test in angular2 using karma jasmine

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-runner

```
<input type="checkbox" class="mocked_as_radio_button" 
(keyup.space)="spaceKeyPress($event)">
```

I have an input element which is a checkbox.
I want to simulate keyup.space event to test the functionality of

```
 spaceKeyPress($event)
```

Don't want to use jQuery.

Answer (score 7):

I guess you're looking for:

```
debugElement.triggerEventHandler('keyup.space', {});
```

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/qvon2oP6VTHY668tjbvF?p=preview)**

See also angular2 documentation

- [https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/testing.html#!#*triggereventhandler*](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/testing.html#!#_triggereventhandler_)

Comment: `triggerEventHandler()` is not firing up the actual `keyup.space` event that's why I am unable to reach `spaceKeyPress($event)`

Comment: How do you want to use $event?

Comment: there is a handler `spaceKeyPress` in which I am just manipulating the value of checkbox. To be more specific I dont need that `$event` I just want that the checkbox doesn't change it's value on `keyup.space`.
It's functionality is implemented but I am not getting it how to test it.

Comment: Can you add your test in my plunker?